# Getting wrong Hostname from tracert

Tags: domain-name-system, vpn, hostname

Noticed this while using VNC to users computers. When I do a tracert using hostname it completes but at a different hostname. All my users are using Microsoft VPN. I'm assuming this is a DNS issue but I'm not sure where to look for the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's reverse DNS. Whatever DNS server you are using is either not tied in with those machines, or perhaps it's that the computers that are VPNing in are not always registering their VPN DNS address, so an old one is still there.

If you are doing AD integrated DNS, it's also possible that the reverse DNS entries do not have permissions to be changed by the computers that are VPNing in.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll have to take a look into that when I get a chance.